# C - Saving an element to an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, while-loop, scanf

I save in an array that I have statically allocated and I don't know how many will be at the input of the element, I only know that there will be fewer of them than I have reserved for the array. Using this input, I can't save the last element in the array.

```
int nactiCisla (int delky[], int *cnt) 
{
    int x;
    int q = 0;
        
    printf("Delky nosniku: \n");
    
        while  (( scanf("%d", &x) ) == 1) 
        {
            
                delky[q] = x;
                q++;
            
        }
    
    return q;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure that you do not add more elements than those allowed by the array. Second you can make the function more generic by accepting also the first position to insert (*e.g.,* `begin`)

```
int nactiCisla (int delky[], int begin, int end) 
{
    int x;
    int current_pos = begin;
    printf("Delky nosniku: \n");
    for(;current_pos < end && ( scanf("%d", &x) ) == 1; current_pos++) 
        delky[current_pos] = x;
    
    return current_pos;
}
```

This way you can choose the exact part of the array where you gone add the elements. For instance, to add only two elements into the array on its third and forth position you would call that function like this `nactiCisla (delky, 3, 5)`. I am assuming that the `begin` parameter is bigger or equal to zero, and that the `end` parameter is at most the size of the array.

This function will stop adding elements into the array when either the current array position is bigger than the `end` that you have passed as parameter, or you have entered a value that is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is, but is this what you are looking for?

```
int nactiCisla (int delky[], int *cnt) 
{
    printf("Delky nosniku: \n");
    for ( *cnt = 0; scanf("%d", &delky[q]) == 1; *cnt++ );
    return *cnt;
}
```

Comment: No, I have an array size in cnt. Using scanf I load the elements into the array and in the variable q I have the number of loaded elements.

Comment: Why do you need `cnt` if you are sure you are never going to read too many elements? It is good practice to know array limit, but then you should use it as well.